# Undefined index error on validation - PHP

Tags: php

Hi first let me tell you I'm posting a "summary" of my code here NOT because I havent tried solving my issue or I'm lazy. Because of my little knowledge on PHP struggling to crack the error now for 3.5hrs!

So im much grateful if someone can point out why this error is happening. The error says undefined error in line 4.

```
        <?php 
    function validate(&$x,&$y)
    {if(isset($_POST['sub1']))
        {if($_POST['optMe'] == "") {echo "Empty dropdown"; return false;}}
    }
    function display($x,$y)
    {
    ?>
    <html>
    <head><title></title></head>
    <body>
    <form method="POST">
      <table id="tab2" border="1">
      <tr><td>
            <select id="optMe">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="one">one</option>
            <option value="two">two</option>
            </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="submit" id="sub1" name="sub1" value="Click here"></td>
      </tr> 
      </table>
    </form>
    <form method="POST">
      <table id="tab2" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="send now"></td>
      </tr>     
      </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    }
    function process($x)
    {
    // I will add my code here to print something.
    }
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
        {$formValues = $_POST;$formErrors = array();
        if (!validate($formValues, $formErrors))
        display($formValues, $formErrors);
        else
        process($formValues);
        }
        else
        display(null, null);
    ?>
```

Comment: Code is also weird in that you're assigning $_POST to $formValues, then passing that to the validate function, but still using the global $_POST . . . no reason to pass anything if you're going to be using using the globals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<select>` has no `name` attribute, so it doesn't get sent, so `$_POST['optMe']` doesn't exist, so you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

You have not given a name attribute to your form field:

```
<select id="optMe">
```

should be:

```
<select name="optMe" id="optMe">
```